# Using expression in OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa

I have two entities

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="MASTER")  
public class Master {  
    @Id  
    @Column(name="MASTER")  
    private Integer id;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="master")  
    private List<Detail> details;    

    ...  
}  

@Entity  
@Table(name="DETAIL")  
public class Detail {  
    @ManyToOne  
    @JoinColumn(name="MASTER",referencedColumnName="MASTER")
    private Master master;
    ...  
}
```

The tables `MASTER` and `DETAIL`, where those entities are `persisted`, are really old dbase tables `(.dbf files with .mdx indexes)` with some particularities, the worst being the kind of indexes they use.

Table DETAIL has an index based on the expression "str(MASTER, 7)", and that index is only used by the jdbc driver if the sql sentece uses the same formula.

With the code above, the `sql` statement that is executed to retrieve the master's details is

```
SELECT MASTER, ..., FROM DETAIL WHERE MASTER = ?
```

and that doesn't use the `index`, so the performance is really, really bad.

Is there any way that I can annotate the classes so that the SQL executed is

```
SELECT MASTER, ..., FROM DETAIL WHERE STR(MASTER,7) = STR(?,7)?
```

I don't mind using `eclipselink` extensions (or moving to `hibernate`) if I have to.

If that is not possible, what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If your query is JPQL you can use,

```
Select d from Detail d where FUNC('STR', d.master.id, 7) = FUNC('STR', :id, 7)
```

If you are trying to customize the mapping, you can use a DescriptorCustomizer to override the Expression or SQL for the selectQuery,

```
mapping.setSelectionSQLString("select * from detail where str(master, 7) = str(#MASTER, 7)")
```

If you are trying to customize the find() query, you can use a DescriptorCustomizer to override the SQL for the readObject on the descriptor's queryManager.